# Two SSL certificates configured at the same time on a Java server application

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore

I am investigating the possibility to configure two certificates (one signed with SHA1 and the other signed with SHA256 ) on a Java server. Specifically, I have created a keystore in which I have imported two certificates. This keystore was then set to be used by my simple java server application with the following sintax:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","key.jks");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "myPassword");
```

Here is the problem I have identified. When using the openSSL tool to list the certificates used by the port opened on my secure socket (ran the command while the server was running and listening for connections), I can see that only ONE certificate is used, the other one is ignored.

The question is: is there any way that I can tell my server to use both certificates at the same time? This is needed as I am also having two java client applications which should be able to communicate with the server. One of them is trusting SHA1 signed cert and the other is trusting SHA2 cert.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know, but I highly doubt it.  Besides that, it is really highly recommended to stop trusting SHA1 certificates. If the known ability to find collisions in SHA1 becomes [as bad as the situation with MD5](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2012/06/06/flame-malware-collision-attack-explained/), you would be putting user data at serious risk by supporting a certificate signed with an insecure hash function.  This means you really ought to upgrade the client.

Comment: Which certificate belongs to the server's Private Key?

Comment: My server's keystore contains both certificates, but when I am listing the actual certificates used by my socket port, I can see that only the first added certificate is used. I even created two different types of certificates (one using the RSA algorithm and the other DSA) and configured my client A to trust only the RSA cert and my client B to trust only the DSA cert. It made no difference, the connection server-client was not successful. I know that SHA1 is not recommended anymore, but the upgrade is not an option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

She was referring to the transition phase. Since the clients are not under the server owner's control, their upgrade cannot be enforced. For a limited period of time, new clients that only know & trust the new SHA256 certificate will connect to the server while older clients that only know & trust the old SHA1 signed certificates must be still able to connect to the server as well. That's why this transition period is required.

Comment: Who is "she" in your answer?